# Bitwise-operators in c 23 << (23 >> 2)

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

How would you code this problem: 23 << (23 >> 2)
and how would you solve it by hand?
We have to do this for an assignment in college, any help would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Hello, show us what you have done so far :)

Comment: 1. Divide `23` by `2` 2 times to calculate `23 >> 2` 2. Making sure that it is small enough not to cause overflow, write code: `int main(void) { printf("%d\n", 23 << (23 >> 2)); }` (`#include <stdio.h>` is omitted because we cannot write newline here)

Answer (score 1):

Convert 23 to binary: 0b10111

Shift right 0b10111 (ie23) by two: 0b101

Convert 0b101 to decimal: 5

Shift left 23 in binary by 5: 0b1011100000